# Using Text Mask component with Ant design Input

Tags: antd, text-mask

I have been testing '[react-text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask)' library and I want to use this component together with ant design Input component using its render attribute. However, it doesn't show formatted text.

```
<TextMask
        mask={[/[12]/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, "-", /[01]/, /\d/, "-", /[0-3]/, /\d/]}
        placeholderChar="_"
        showMask
        render={(ref, props) => (
          <Input
            name="phone"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Hey I am Ant design Input"
            required
            ref={ref}
            {...props}
          />
        )}
      />
```

If I change the  tag with  It shows formatted text like we expect.

My main intention to show every input component should be displayed like an ant design component.

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/6jjmy8rlqr)

You can make it using [react-input-mask](http://sanniassin.github.io/react-input-mask/demo.html) library.